# Angular 2 append click button

Tags: angular

I have a form that stores an undefined number of pairs: *label/value*:

```
<form (submit)=new_answers_for_this_question()>
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col m5">
        <input placeholder="Label" id="label" type="text" class="validate">
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col m5">
        <input placeholder="Value" id="values" type="text" class="validate">
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col m2 center-align">
        <button class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light" (click)="new_answer()"><i class="material-icons">add</i></button>
    </div>
</div>
<button>Insert Answers</button>
</form>
```

I just want to fill both input and then press the `add button` to add a new line with a new *label/value* `input`, previous `add button` will disappear, and a new button to append a new possible line. Using `jQuery` is simple as `append` the full row div on the parent div but using angular I dont know how to handle this, ¿any ideas?

Edit: The purpose is to insert a row per pair of label and value for the same question in the DataBase.

i.e.:

```
**Question 1**
Label: 'good', value: '7-10'
Label: 'neutral', Value: '4-6'
Label: 'bad', Value: '1-3'
```

Comment: Use a loop (`*ngFor`) over an array to which you add an item when the user presses "Add".

Comment: But the first time I need an input, with a loop the first time will be empty, then no input are displayed

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
angular.module('submitExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.list = [];
     
      $scope.submit = function() {
        if ($scope.text) {
          $scope.list.push(this.text);
          $scope.text = '';
        }
      };
    }]);
```

```html
  

<form ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  Enter text and hit enter:
  <input type="text" ng-model="text" name="text" />
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
  <pre>{{list}}</pre>
</form>
```

Comment: The question is asking about Angular, not AngularJS.

Comment: I want that previous label/value pairs to be input because maybe user want to change it, so must be connected with the model i guess :/

Comment: I have updated the plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/aCe5ZkU2UHxEEolAY07e?p=preview with what Im looking for, how can i save all the form? could it work?